# How to reverse search in Excel?

Tags: excel, string, vba, text, excel-formula

I have a text in a worksheet like:

> The girl is very beautiful

I want a formula to perform a search from right to left for the word "very", and if found then extract it to some other region of the sheet.

Note: Purpose of doing reverse search is because I want to implement it in my workbook which requires reverse search.

At least, say me how to revert the text like this :

> beautiful very is girl The

Then I can do a normal search.  I don't know VBA so please give some formula.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: I think your choices are to use a complicated array formula, or VBA.

Comment: How do you plan on extracting the word once you find it?  (This might affect your answer.)  Do you know how you would extract if searching from left-to-right?

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes i know how to extract from left to right

Comment: @Everyone Got my answer myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### VBA Function to reverse the words in text:

```
Public Function StrReverse(strIn As String, Optional Delimiter As String = " ") As String
    'Reverse the words in 'StrIn', split on a "Space" unless 'Delimiter' is specified
    Do While InStrRev(strIn, Delimiter) <> 0
        StrReverse = StrReverse & Delimiter & Right(strIn, Len(strIn) - InStrRev(strIn, Delimiter))
        strIn = Trim(Left(strIn, InStrRev(strIn, Delimiter) - 1))
    Loop
    StrReverse = Trim(StrReverse & Delimiter & strIn)
    If Left(StrReverse, 1) = Delimiter Then StrReverse = Right(StrReverse, Len(StrReverse) - 1)
End Function
```

For example, if cell A1 contains:

> The girl is very beautiful

...then you could enter in another cell:

```
=StrReverse(A1)
```

...which would return:

> beautiful very is girl The

---

### To add a custom VBA function to a workbook:

- Copy the code for the function you want to add to Excel (from above).
- In an Excel, workbook, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA Editor (VBE).
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> to insert a new module.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste in the code.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to return to Excel.

---

**Edit #1**:

Added optional delimiter to function above (defaults to a " " space).

Also, `FindReverse` (below), which allows VBA's (little-known) `InStrRev` function to be used on worksheets.

```
Public Function FindReverse(StringCheck As String, StringMatch As String, _
    Optional Start As Long = -1) As Long

    'Returns the position number of the last occurrence of 'Stringmatch" 
    'within StringCheck',  Optionally specify the position number from the
    'end to begin the search.  (-1 = Begin at the end)

    FindReverse = InStrRev(StringCheck, StringMatch, Start)

End Function
```

---

**Edit #2**:

<sub>*LOL @ Myself* ... I'm always telling people not to try to recreate functionality that's already built into MS Office, and it seems that I unwittingly did the same thing -- even giving it the same as the existing VBA Function.</sub>

### **Built-in VBA function:**

[image: StrReverse syntax]

I realize that it's not identical functionality as the `StrReverse` function I wrote (above) but I suspect it also could have solved OP's original inquiry...

Nonetheless, I am *really* surprised that VBA even *allows* a custom function to have the same name as a built-in function!

<sub>***How to confuse VBA:***</sub>
[image: StrReverse(StrReverse)]

Comment: dawg I don't know whether it works or not, I don't have time to verify still I am accepting your answer for your efforts

Comment: Was thinking it might be better to add an optional delimiter in case it's not a space that's being searched for. `Public Function StrReverse(strIn As String, Optional Delimiter As String = " ") As String`  It doesn't work without a space though so would need a rewrite.

Comment: ...not really a rewrite; a quick fix (done).  Also a function for `InStrRev`, one of a number of VBA functions that (_annoyingly_) can't normally be called  directly from a worksheet.