# Formula to extract usernames of instagram links in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, google-docs

[image]I have a list of instagram url's in a excel sheet and i need to extract their user names into another column using a formula.

I have used this formula but it's incomplete and does not work as i need.

```
=RIGHT(C111,FIND("/",C111))
```

For example, how can i extract the user name **stack_test** from the url https://www.instagram.com/stack_test/ which is in a excel sheet.

Comment: page is unavailable. Could you please paste any example?

Comment: @Error1004 i was just giving an example. Do you know how to extract stact_test part from the url

Comment: I have already given a similar answer here. You can check out the formula here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377210/

Answer (score 1):

If you need user names only then you can do it without formula.
You can use Text to Column (Short Cut:Alt + D then E).
Select Delimited, In delemeters dialog select Other and use /.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** `FILTERXML XPATH` argument changed.  *After doing some research, discovered you can specify "next to last" node, instead of using the `LOOKUP` function.*

If your version of Excel has the `FILTERXML` function, you can use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-1]")
```

If you have an older version of Excel, you can use:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="/",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1),"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("com/",A1)+4,(SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","^^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))-(FIND("com/",A1)+4)))
```

Comment: Formula should be written to extract the word between / and / from the end of the url

Comment: The proposed answer is just a guessing. Please provide a sample of your data. Url has a lot of "/" in it. what exactly you want to extract.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of my excel sheet. What i need to do is extract the usernames of the given instagram links to D column. For example just ASSUME there's a url like this , https://www.instagram.com/stack_test/. I want to extract stack_test part of the url

Comment: Hey Thanks alot.It's working. Just one thing. How can i remove the last " / " character?

Comment: i have change the naswer.

Answer (score 0):

This works if there are exactly two `/` in each row, and the username is between them.

Type `some_text/username/some_other_text` in cell A1.

I broke down the formula in multiple cells to make it more readable, but you can make a one-cell formula:

B1: `=FIND("/",A1)`

C1: `=FIND("/",A1,B1+1)`

D1: `=MID(A1,B1+1,C1-B1-1)` . This will show `username`

If there can be multiple `/` and you only need the last two, it is more complicated. You might want to have a look:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350264/how-can-i-perform-a-reverse-string-search-in-excel-without-using-vba) and [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4934-excel-reverse-find.html) (non-VBA examples)
- or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004759/how-to-reverse-search-in-excel) (VBA)